# How change audio language name in exoplayer

Tags: java, android, kotlin, media-player, exoplayer

I am developing an app with exoplayer and I pass a video file with two audio for different languages my problem is in app when user want change audio it shows two audio but both of them are english while one of them is not english so i want change the name that exoplayer shows for that one to the correct word. how can I change audio language name in exoplayer?

Comment: Did you find the solution?